# Extending a line (e.g. road) using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I followed the instructions provided in the Help menu i.e. edit, select feature, edit vertices, and then used the continue feature tool to extend the line.

Why is the continue feature tool greyed out?

Comment: Select destination Iine, click on extend, click on line to be extended

Comment: Can you add a new line? if so add a fresh new line snapping the first vertex to your existing line, select both the new and line you want to continue and editor::merge, make sure you select the original line to merge into. This is not intended to be a workaround, I just want to test your data. If that works then we'll have to dig a bit deeper. Is your map and data spatial reference set? If one or the other is Undefined that could cause this problem (note: you can only change the map spatial reference if you're not editing).

Comment: I tried, Based on ArcGIS 10.3 manual it work's perfectly, read manual aagain and follow instruction step by step,select first feature and then select endpoint in second feature. use "Extend Tool" in "Advance editing" please search in manual "Extending a line by sketching" but if you had more problem let me know, you can find Advance editing in Editor -> More editing tools

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I found I can extend a line (eg road) to any end point (not necessarily another feature-could be just a 'dead end') as follows:  1. edit/start editing  2. select layer (feature class) to edit eg roads/OK/select road feature/select line construction tool  3. select on end point/digitise new road extension/ double click to finish  4.  select both original road and new road extension (hold shift key to select both) 5. editor/merge/save edits. Worked a treat!!

Comment: Please copy/paste your comment into an answer.  Self-answering is fine to do and should help you to unlock the functionality to get much more benefit from the site.

Answer (score 1):

The asker found that they:

> can extend a line (eg road) to any end point (not necessarily another
>   feature-could be just a 'dead end') as follows:
>
> 1. edit/start editing
> 2. select layer (feature class) to edit eg roads/OK/select road feature/select line construction tool
> 3. select on end point/digitise new road extension/ double click to finish
> 4. select both original road and new road extension (hold shift key to select both)
> 5. editor/merge/save edits.